# db2 IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() behaviour

Tags: sql, db2

I would like to retrieve last ID created for an identity columns right after an insert and I want to use IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL(). During my tests I have 2 different behaviors.

When I user a instruction like this it works fine.

```
 INSERT INTO(fld1,fld2, ..) VALUES (val1,val2 )
```

but when I call a more complex insert I am returned NULL. I have something like

```
 INSERT INTO(fld1,fld2, ..) SELECT a,b,c,.. FROM tbl1,tbl2.. WHERE ...
```

Is it becasue do It really works only with INSERT/VALUE calls or shuold I have a look at something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO Tablename(fld1,fld2, ..) VALUES (val1,val2 )

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO Tablename(fld1,fld2, ..) SELECT a,b,c,.. FROM tbl1,tbl2.. WHERE ...

SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Comment: I am not sure if db2 supports SCOPE_IDENTITY() function.

Comment: Doesn't work either. The Insert works fine but the select SCOPE_IDENTITY() Fails.

Answer (score 2):

Just use this:

`VALUES IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL()`

Answer (score -1):

The correct syntax to retrieve the last inserted identity column is:

`SELECT IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() AS IDENTITY FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1`

Comment: Returns null, too. If you do `SELECT IDENTITY_VAL_LOCAL() FROM DUAL`, you get a column name with the wanted ID while the row value is still `NULL`

Comment: Agreed ... This doesn't work as I'm getting just a long list of NULL.